# Using ctable package with apa6 class

Tags: tables, apa6, ctable

I'm trying to use `ctable` since it's much easier to work with than `threeparttable` and all of its additional packages but I get an error stating that "Command `\tnote` already defined".

I think it's something to do with the `apa6` class but I don't know how to change that.

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{ctable}
\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}

\ctable[
caption = Some caption,
pos = h
]{ccc}{
}{\FL
A & B & C\ML
1 & 2 & 3\NN
4 & 5 & 6\LL
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It wasn't clear from the question, but just in case: the apa6 class automatically loads the threeparttable package, and also defines its own `\tnote` command for use in those tables. You may have to stick with its use of threeparttable.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Mike in comment, [`apa6`](http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6) loads [`threeparttable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) which defines `\tnote`. As such, "undefining" `\tnote` via

```
\let\tnote\relax
```

resolves the conflict between [`ctable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable) and `threeparttable`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}% http://ctan.org/pkg/apa6
\let\tnote\relax% "Free up" \tnote for use in ctable
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\shorttitle{}
\begin{document}
\ctable[
    caption = Some caption,
    pos = h
  ]{ccc}{
  }{\FL
    A & B & C\ML
    1 & 2 & 3\NN
    4 & 5 & 6\LL
  }
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, use the `threeparttable` format as suggested by Mike.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the issue in jou mode but gives me errors in man mode. Do you happen to know why this is the issue?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're trying to get out of `ctable`, it might be easiest to stick with `threeparttable`, since `apa6` automatically loads it. Slightly adapted example including a footnote (like what `ctable`'s `\tnote` would do):

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa6}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{A complex table}
\label{tab:ComplexTable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lrrl@{}} \toprule
Distribution type & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Percentage of} & Total \\
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{targets with} & trials per \\
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{segment in} & participant \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
& Onset & Coda & \\
\midrule
Categorical -- onset\tabfnm{a} & 100 & 0 & 196 \\
Probabilistic & 80 & 20 & 200 \\
& 60 & 40 & 160 \\
Categorical -- coda & 0 & 100 & 196 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} \\
\tabfnt{a}{A footnote about categorical -- onset}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Credit where credit is due: the example is straight from the manual (Beitzel, 2012)

Comment: My mistake in not making that more explicit. I said "slightly modified" instead of "cut down from `apa6` documentation", assuming the poster would find where `threeparttable` was used, since they were already using `apa6`.